# Flutter overlay with position relative to parent

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a ListView. I am trying to have an overlay when I click on a button that is on each element of the listview, but I can't find a way to make an overlay with a position relative to the item in the ListView.

The code I have (that was copied from some answer here in stackoverflow) is this

```
InkWell(          
      onTap: () {            
        return Overlay.of(context).insert(OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
          return Align(
            child: Container(
              width: 56,
              height: 56,                
              child: Material(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => print('ON TAP OVERLAY!'),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.redAccent),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }));           
      },
      child: Icon(
        Icons.arrow_back,
        color: Colors.black,
        size: 34,
      ),
    ),
```

Is there a way that the position is relative to the element in the list view (preferably dynamically, so if I scroll the list, the overlay will scroll together with the list item)

Thank you very much

Comment: Why not putting the 'overlay part' inside single 'listView item' each?

Comment: @yellowgray I need the overlay part to overflow the list view item

Comment: If you want to align to the listview item, it is easier to make them together ( you can check [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) and [OverflowBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/OverflowBox-class.html) ).

Comment: @yellowgray z-index of list view is not ediable, so even if it overflows, I assume (I have not tried) that the bottom next list view item will cover what overflows from the previous list view item